# Deselect images photo_manager package in flutter using PhotoManager.presentLimited()

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am working with flutter using [photo_manager](https://pub.dev/packages/photo_manager#from-id) because I need to create a custom image picker, but I have tried to handle de iOS options first, one of them is "Select Photos..." which opens the native gallery
[native gallery image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIf9N.png)

And there is my problem, when I reopen the gallery it keeps the image selected even if I restart the application.

I need to deselect all the images when the user leaves the page.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:photo_manager/photo_manager.dart';

class ServicePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const ServicePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: const Center(
        child: Text('Hello World'),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(onPressed: () async {
        // the method can use optional param `permission`.
        final PermissionState permission = await PhotoManager.requestPermissionExtend();
        
        if (permission.isAuth) {
          print('Allow Access to All Photos');
          // Granted
          // You can to get assets here.
        } else if (permission.hasAccess) {

          print('Select Photos...');

          //opens native ios gallery 
          await PhotoManager.presentLimited();

          // Access will continue, but the amount visible depends on the user's selection.
        } else {
          print('Dont Allow');
          // Limited(iOS) or Rejected, use `==` for more precise judgements.
          // You can call `PhotoManager.openSetting()` to open settings for further steps.
        }
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried to clear cache but it doesn't seem to deselect the images

```
     await PhotoManager.clearFileCache();
     await PhotoManager.releaseCache();
```